# Custom Prototype Cell designed in Storyboard with Custom View Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

The main problem is that it does not respect the design done in the storyboard. The coordinates of the image and the labels are as a basic cell. Note that such attributes are observed as the alignment of the label.

The button that has been added, is below the label.
[image: screenshot xCode UITableViewCell vs StoryBoard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've definitely seen this issue before and I believe it is because imageView and textLabel are properties of UITableViewCell and the default implementation of layoutSubviews is overriding your storyboard's layout with UITableViewCell's defaults.

Try overriding layoutSubviews, or provide your own image and label properties (named differently from UITableViewCell's, ie: myImageView and myTextLabel).

Comment: @Nicholas Yes. With another names of properties, it's working but I wanted to use the UITableViewCell interface.

I get your explanation, thanks, it's a shame it does not work how we want.